# Make kramdown's ALDs available on entire Jekyll site

Tags: jekyll, kramdown

I'm using Jekyll to make a site that makes frequent use of kramdown's [attribute list definitions](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html#block-attributes). However the only way I can make this work right now is to include all of the definitions in every page e.g.

```
{:def1: ...}
{:def2: ...}
{:def3: ...}
```

This seems really smelly to me since if I want to change a definition, I need to do so in every single page. Ugh.

Is it possible to put these definitions somewhere where they will be included in every page? I tried putting them in a layout but it seems that Jekyll won't parse markdown in layouts.

I'm also open to alternatives to ALDs if this is not the right way to go about things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add definitions to your posts, you can also create an .md file in your _includes folder with definitions like:

```
*[def1]: ...
*[def2]: ...
```

And then you can add this file to every post using `{% include definitions.md %}`.

Comment: Ideally I would like to skip the `{% include ... %}` bit as well, but at least this lets me have all the definitions in one place. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be in the `_layouts` folder. Try keeping it in the ***_includes*** folder and then include it with this tag `{% include definitions.html %}`